# Are there any known localstorage compatibility issues with android webview

Tags: android, android-webview, local-storage

We will develop a hybrid app, using `localstorage` as http cache , and it will shared with multiple webview.

so are there any known localstorage `compatibility` issues ?

android 2.1 ~ 4.x  (most for 2.3 ~ 4.x)

Answer (score 1):

First of all I don't think that the local storage could be a suitable solution for caching, because it's funcionality only includes the possibility to save/retrieve/delete key/value pairs, but I don't know exactly what your purposes are.

About the compatibility I would say that the local storage of the android's WebView does not function very well, because it is not persistent across the different tabs/windows, so actually it becomes useless in my opinion. If you want to share the same data in multiple webviews the only way is to use a java database and a javascript interface. There is a implementation on [github](https://github.com/didimoo/AndroidLocalStorage), which should be suitable for that.

Comment: thanks, I'm using angular, and want to cache the http response(json) for a long time & share between webviews.